# Blank Screen appearing in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-fullstack

**Initially there is some output but later Blank Screen is appearing in the Window**

In the Code Editor there is no error but there is no output visible, initially it was visible but after adding some more code in Skills.jsx especially, the output has disappeared.
Please help me with this.

*This is the App.js*

```
import { About, Footer, Header, Skills, Testimonial, Work} from './container'
import { Navbar } from './components';
import './App.scss';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
        <Navbar/>
        <Header/>
        <About/>
        <Work/>
        <Skills/>
        <Testimonial/>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*Skills.jsx*

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';

import {AppWrap} from '../../wrapper';
import {urlFor,client} from '../../client';
import './Skills.scss';

const Skills = () => {
  const [experience, setExperience] = useState([]);
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query ='*[_type == "experiences"]';
    const skillsQuery ='*[_type == "skills"]';
    
    client.fetch(query)
      .then((data)=>{
        setExperience(data);
      })

      client.fetch(skillsQuery)
      .then((data)=>{
        setSkills(data);
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">Skills and Experience</h2>

      <div className="app__skills-container">
        <motion.div className="app__skills-list">
          {Skills.map((skill)=>(
            <motion.div
              whileInView={{opacity:[0,1]}}
              transition={{duration:0.5}}
              className="app__skills-item app__flex"
              key={skill.name}
            >
              <div className="app__flex" style={{backgroundColor:skill.bgColor}}>
                <img src={urlFor(skill.icon)} alt={skill.name} />
              </div>
              <p className="p-text">{skill.name}</p>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Skills
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'))
```

[Blank Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFPrH.png)

Comment: see `console` tab of dev tools.

Comment: Open browser console and check the logs.

Comment: Do you properly have skills (no capital S) , assuming that is correct keep in mind the version of React you are using does not need createRoot approach (if no error in console you probably got that right)

Comment: Check the logs. There is a possibility of something undefined in Skills.jsx because of the api call. if that's the case, set a loading state.

Comment: I agree with Wiston Coronell, try changing `Skills.map` to `skills.map` -> its confusing the `Skills` component and the `skills` variable otherwise :)